# Java Bean Validations not working in a Spring Project

Tags: java, spring, rest, bean-validation

I have a **Spring** project and I'm looking to use a **REST controller** for some operation. I have a request class defined for the request body of the method. I added several **NotEmpty validations** to the request class and the **Valid annotation** in the controller method.

However, those validations don't do anything at all, a request passes through them like they don't exist.

The controller:

```
import com.example.project.rest.data.request.UserRegisterRequest;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import javax.validation.Valid;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/users")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserController {
    @PostMapping(value = "/register",
            consumes = "application/json",
            produces = "application/json"
    )
    public ResponseEntity<String> registerUser(@RequestBody @Valid UserRegisterRequest userRegisterRequest) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(userRegisterRequest.getPassword(), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

}
```

The request body (I've also tried with other validations):

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.validation.constraints.*;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserRegisterRequest {

    @NotEmpty
    private String firstName;

    @NotEmpty
    private String lastName;

    @NotEmpty
    private String email;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Password is mandatory")
    private String password;

}
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>project</name>
    <description>project</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>1.18.24</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>1.5.3.Final</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <compilerArg>
                            -Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=spring
                        </compilerArg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

The request I send from Insomnia (it just returns 201-Created with no response body):

```
{
  "firstName": "Thomas",
  "lastName": "James",
  "email": "thomasjames@email.com"
}
```

dependency tree:

```
 com.example:project:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
 +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:2.7.5:compile
 |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:2.7.5:compile
 |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.9.7:compile
 |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:2.7.5:compile
 |  |  +- com.zaxxer:HikariCP:jar:4.0.3:compile
 |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:5.3.23:compile
 |  +- jakarta.transaction:jakarta.transaction-api:jar:1.3.3:compile
 |  +- jakarta.persistence:jakarta.persistence-api:jar:2.2.3:compile
 |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.6.12.Final:compile
 |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.4.3.Final:compile
 |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.12.18:compile
 |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
 |  |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.4.2.Final:compile
 |  |  +- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.5.1:compile
 |  |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.1.2.Final:compile
 |  |  \- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:2.3.7:compile
 |  |     +- org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:jar:2.3.7:compile
 |  |     +- com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:jar:3.0.12:compile
 |  |     \- com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:jar:1.2.2:runtime
 |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:2.7.5:compile
 |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.7.5:compile
 |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:5.3.23:compile
 |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.3.23:compile
 |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.3.23:compile
 |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.3.23:compile
 |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.36:compile
 |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:5.3.23:compile
 +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:jar:2.7.5:compile
 |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.7.5:compile
 |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.7.5:compile
 |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.11:compile
 |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.11:compile
 |  |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.17.2:compile
 |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.17.2:compile
 |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.36:compile
 |  |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:1.3.5:compile
 |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.30:compile
 |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.3.23:compile
 |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:5.7.4:compile
 |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:5.7.4:compile
 |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.3.23:compile
 +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.7.5:compile
 |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.7.5:compile
 |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.13.4.2:compile
 |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.13.4:compile
 |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.13.4:compile
 |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.13.4:compile
 |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.13.4:compile
 |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.7.5:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:9.0.68:compile
 |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:9.0.68:compile
 |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.3.23:compile
 |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.3.23:compile
 +- org.springframework.session:spring-session-core:jar:2.7.0:compile
 |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.3.23:compile
 +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:jar:2.7.5:runtime
 |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.7.5:compile
 |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.7.5:compile
 +- org.postgresql:postgresql:jar:42.3.7:runtime
 |  \- org.checkerframework:checker-qual:jar:3.5.0:runtime
 +- org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:1.18.24:compile
 +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.7.5:test
 |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.7.5:test
 |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.7.5:test
 |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.7.0:test
 |  |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.4.8:test
 |  |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:2.4.8:test
 |  |        \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:9.1:test
 |  +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:2.3.3:compile
 |  |  \- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:1.2.2:compile
 |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.22.0:test
 |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest:jar:2.2:test
 |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:jar:5.8.2:test
 |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.8.2:test
 |  |  |  +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.2.0:test
 |  |  |  +- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.8.2:test
 |  |  |  \- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.2:test
 |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:jar:5.8.2:test
 |  |  \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.8.2:test
 |  |     \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.8.2:test
 |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:4.5.1:test
 |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.12.18:test
 |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:3.2:test
 |  +- org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:jar:4.5.1:test
 |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.1:test
 |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
 |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.3.23:compile
 |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.3.23:test
 |  \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.9.0:test
 +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-test:jar:5.7.4:test
 |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:5.7.4:compile
 |     \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:jar:5.7.4:compile
 +- org.mapstruct:mapstruct:jar:1.5.3.Final:compile
 +- org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:jar:1.5.3.Final:compile
 +- org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:jar:1.6.12:compile
 |  +- org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-webmvc-core:jar:1.6.12:compile
 |  |  \- org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-common:jar:1.6.12:compile
 |  |     \- io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-core:jar:2.2.4:compile
 |  |        +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.12.0:compile
 |  |        +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:jar:2.13.4:compile
 |  |        +- io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-annotations:jar:2.2.4:compile
 |  |        \- io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-models:jar:2.2.4:compile
 |  +- org.webjars:swagger-ui:jar:4.14.3:compile
 |  +- org.webjars:webjars-locator-core:jar:0.50:compile
 |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.13.4:compile
 |  \- io.github.classgraph:classgraph:jar:4.8.149:compile
 \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:jar:2.7.5:compile
    +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:9.0.68:compile
    \- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.2.5.Final:compile
       \- jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:jar:2.0.2:compile
```

Security Configuration:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration{
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Bean Configuration:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
public class BeanConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
```

I just can't seem to understand why they don't work. I've searched everywhere and couldn't find a solution.

Can someone help?

Comment: Is that your actual code and full `pom.xml` or a modified/simplified version of what you have? One thing in your pom you declare Java17 but your compiler is then again Java 1.8? Which `@Valid` and `@NotEmpty` are you using?

Comment: I haven't included the package and imports from my code, but I've added them now. That's my full `pom.xml`. I have modified from 1.8 to 17, but still the same problem. I'm using the `@Valid` and `@NotEmpty` from `javax.validation`.

Comment: Have you tried refreshing your dependencies? Generallyl this is due to some mixup in dependencies, but as you have `spring-boot-starter-validation` that should be ok. Unless you override the version to a newer `hibernate-validator` version or API version (but if this is your full pom that shouldn't be the case).

Comment: Another thing that popped in my mind, do you have a configuration for the web? Like something with `@EnableWebMvc`? As that would disable large parts of the auto-configuration from Spring (Boot).

Comment: I've tried refreshing them, but no, it doesn't work. And no, I don't have any web configuration. I have created a test project with three dependencies (starter-web, devtools and starter-validation) and the spring-boot-maven-plugin and it works. Maybe this is caused by some dependency in my current project. Guess I have to verify them one by one.

Comment: If this is your full pom and you really don't have any configuration apart from the defaults it should work. So I suspect there is something you haven't included in your post that is causing this.

Comment: That's my full pom. I looked through the dependency tree and it seems that `springdoc-openapi-ui` uses `jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:jar:2.0.2` and `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` uses `javax.validation:validation-api:jar:2.0.1.Final`, besides the `spring-boot-starter-validation` that uses `jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:jar:2.0.2` through the hibernate validator. Is this a problem?

Comment: Well it means you have at least jars with duplicate dependencies. I would expect that `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` and `spring-boot-starter-validation` would use the same. You could try and exclude the `openapi` dependency and see what it does.

Comment: Still doesn't work. I'll take the dependencies one by one and see which one causes the problem. Otherwise, I don't know.

Comment: You can add the output of `mvn dependency:tree` to your question. Also make sure you don't have any `@Configuration` classes that override things or stuff in your `application.properties`.

Comment: I added the tree to the question. I only have two `@Configuration` classes, one for beans and one for security that disables CSRF.

Comment: Can you add the `@Configuration` classes. I also wonder if this is your full controller or if there are additional annotations.

Comment: Added them. That's my full controller, nothing else.

Answer (score -1):

These annotations are part of JSR 380 specification. The specification does not contain the implementation details of the annotations. You need to add the implementation library of the validation API.

**Hibernate Validator** is the reference implementation of the validation API. So, adding the hibernate validator dependency will resolve the issue:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.13.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: That dependency is already part of the `spring-boot-starter-validation` dependency he has. Adding it again, tied to a version even, will make things worse.

Comment: Hmm. @AlexanderPope can you check the dependency tree? And see what version of the hibernate validator is pulled in.

Comment: org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.2.5.Final:compile (version managed from 6.2.5.Final)